# communication between components - emitter not working in Angular

Tags: html, angular

Event emitter is not working in Angular 4. I have got the implementation from the tutorial. please suggest me if there is any other way to accomplish it.

the transmitter component described below.

**.HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
        type="button" (click)="toggleClass()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">muyal</a>
</nav>
```

**.TS**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent {
  @Output() emitClass = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  menuShow = false;

  toggleClass() {
   this.emitClass.emit(this.menuShow);
   this.menuShow = !this.menuShow
  }
}
```

the receiver component described below.Event emitter is not working in Angular 4. I have got the implementation from the tutorial. please suggest me if there is any other way to accomplish it.

**.HTML**

```
<app-welcome (emitClass)="emitClass($event)"></app-welcome>
```

**.TS**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-welcome',
   templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
 })

  export class WelcomeComponent  {
    menuShow:boolean = false;
    emitClass(agreed: boolean) {
    this.menuShow = agreed;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it's the `app-header` component which is emitting the event not the `app-welcome` component in which you have put  `emitClass` event to listen. I think doing following will resolve your problem

```
<app-welcome>
   <app-header (emitClass)="emitClass($event)"></app-header>
</app-welcome>
```

I am assuming that `app-welcome` is top level component and `app-header` is used inside `app-welcome` component and also you have imported `app-header` component correctly.